# Arc length with endpoint in the 4th quadrant, find exact values

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If *t* ends in the fourth quadrant and:

[image]

Find exact values for:

[image]

Comment: First, isn't that just $\sin(t-\frac{\pi}{2})$? You should draw a unit circle, and draw the triangle associated with angle $t$, and then find where angle $t-\frac{\pi}{2}$ must be.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  You should have a formula for $\sin (a+b)$ that you can apply. Since $b=\frac \pi 2$, the formula simplifies.